# when we use test mode in razorpay then actual payment transfer or not in php?

Tags: php, payment-gateway, razorpay

Payment is transfer or not how to know using razorpay in test mode?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your Payment transfer in test mode using card details using
https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/test-card-details/

You can test,your code is successfully working or not using in razorpay account in test mode in transaction